# C atomic operations, if writes are all atomic swaps do I need atomic load?

Tags: c, multithreading, atomic, thread-synchronization, compare-and-swap

I am writing a program in C. FOR SIMPLICITY LETS SAY: There are several variables that many threads can both read and write. Every time one of these is written it is written via an atomic swap (GCC atomic operations, sync and swap). Do I need to use an atomic load every time I read one of these variables, or are the atomic writes sufficient to avoid reading in data mid-write?

Note, anywhere that needs to use data from one of these vars first copies the value:

```
int success = 0;
while ( !success ) {
  int x = shared_x;
  ... work with x, result in y ...
  success = cmp_swap( &shared_x, x, y );
}
```

My question is not about a data race, that is I am not concerned I might loose data. MY concern is that the value of shared_x might change halfway through my reading it. Say it is an 8-byte integer, would this be a potential problem: say shared_x is a 64-bit integer, 8 bytes. Would it be possible that my x = shared_x will copy the first 4 bytes, then something atomically writes to shared_x, then this statement finishes reading the second 4 bytes. This would result in x containing the first 4 bytes of an old value of shared_x, and the last 4 bytes of the new shared_x. I suspect the memory barrier in the atomic swap (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html - using __sync_bool_compare_and_swap) is enough to protect against this... but I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're reading from `shared_x`, calculate something new and then write back to `shared_x`. The value you write to `shared_x` seems to depend on the value you originally read from it.

If that is the case, you have a dependency there, and most probably need to not only make the read atomic, but you need to make the whole operation of "read, calculate, write back" atomic. Meaning, you need to synchronize it. Like with a mutex.

I say "most probably" because I can't be sure if I don't know what the code actually does. You need to analyze what happens in the case of a race condition where thread A writes to `shared_x` while thread B is currently doing a calculation based on the old value of `shared_x` and then writes the result back to it. The value written to it by thread A gets lost forever. I can't know whether this would be problematic for you. Only you can know that. If that race condition is OK, then you don't need to synchronize or make the read atomic.

If you're only interested in making sure that reading from `shared_x` will not get you garbage and don't care about the race condition described above, then the answer is "most probably you don't need to make the read atomic." Instead of me copy&pasting, you can read the details right here:

[Atomicity in C++ : Myth or Reality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002046/atomicity-in-c-myth-or-reality)

Even though the question is for C++, the same holds true for C as well.

Note though that atomics are now in the C standard as well (C11), provided by the `<stdatomic.h>` header and the `_Atomic` type qualifier. But of course not all compilers support C11 yet.

Comment: updated my example, now it shows what happens when something else writes while the new value is calculated, it just starts over and tries again.

Comment: @Exodist The perspective needed here is the whole program, not just that one part of it. You need to do the analysis yourself. Assume a race condition and follow the program logic. If the race condition results in no ill effects at all, you're fine. You can also manually introduce race conditions and observe.

Comment: I must not have asked my question properly. I am not concerned about synchronization of the work. I will update my question above.

Comment: Updated, I want to make sure int x does not get half a value of an old shared_x, and half a value of a new shared_x.

Comment: @Exodist OK. Updated the answer by linking to what looks like a duplicate of your question.

Comment: So essentially on an x86 since aligned reads are atomic this code is safe, but not portable. Not all architectures guarantee this, so atomic_load would be the portable way (assuming I use gcc's atomic load, and by portable I mean portable to any system with gcc)

Comment: @Exodist Yes. Though atomics are now in the C standard as well (C11), provided by the `<stdatomic.h>` header and the `_Atomic` type qualifier. But of course not all compilers support C11 yet.

Comment: Also, and this is important, any decent portable atomic library should realize atomicity is a no-op on x86 for aligned read/writes and simply not do anything. So you gain portability and lose nothing by using these wrappers/libraries.

Comment: @nos, did you read about the gcc atomic swap built-ins? they perform a FULL memory barrier. my code above is psuedocode, I use these http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html specifically __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(...) "no memory operand will be moved across the operation, either forward or backward"