# Is int safe to read from multiple threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, pthreads

I have multiple threads reading same int variable. 
and one thread is writing the value.

I don't care about the race condition.

only my concern is writing and reading int value at same time is memory safe ?

and it will not result in any application crash .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are C++ Reads and Writes of an int atomic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that should be all right.  The only way I can envision that crashing is if one of the threads deallocates the memory backing that integer.  For best results I would also make sure the integers are aligned at `sizeof(int)` boundaries.  (Some CPUs cannot access integers at all without this alignment.  Others provide weaker guarantees of atomicity for unaligned access.)

Comment: make sure the integers are aligned at sizeof(int)
can you please provide more info about that how can I do that ?

Comment: @VivekGoel In most cases your compiler will do it for you.  But there are compiler specific ways to accomplish this, i.e. `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` for GCC.

Comment: @VivekGoel - You can also do things to check this at runtime, i.e. `((uintptr_t)&x) % sizeof(int)` should be zero.  (And you can maybe even add an `assert` for that.)

Comment: @asveikau more portable for gcc should be `__attribute__ ((aligned (__BIGGEST_ALIGNMENT__)))`

Comment: @user411313 +1.  I only wrote 4 there as an example.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, on x86 and x86-64, as long as the value you're reading is aligned properly.  32-bit `int`s, they need to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary in order for access to be [*atomic*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28programming%29) when reading or writing, which will almost always be the case unless you go out of your way to create unaligned `int`s (say, by using a packed structure or by doing casting/pointer arithmetic with byte buffers).

You probably also want to declare your variable as `volatile` so that the compiler will generate code that will re-fetch the variable from memory every time it's accessed.  That will prevent it from making optimizations such as caching it in a register when it might be altered by another thread.

Comment: +1 for volatile and actually mentioning the alignment modulus

Answer (score 1):

On all Linux platforms that I know of, reads and writes of aligned int's are atomic and safe. You will never read a value that wasn't written (no word tearing). You will never cause a fault or crash.

Comment: I think this kind of broad claims really need a reference. Also, precisely _what_ does aligned mean in this context?

Comment: If someone doesn't know what an aligned integer is, they have no business writing multi-threaded programs.

Comment: oh real charming. Also, way over-generalized. Well, you don't need to bother, of course. There are other answers on SO that shed more light.

Comment: Code can get stale values for the variable. For example if it is coming from Registers (because of code optimization).

Comment: @Shamit: That's correct. The OP said he didn't care about that race condition.

Comment: This didn't deserve a downvote.  It's true that a modern CPU will make aligned reads/writes atomic, and they won't generate a fault as long as it's a valid dereference.  +1