# Is pointer assignment atomic in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, variable-assignment, atomic

I've actually heard claims both ways. I suspect they are not, but I wanted to get the topic settled.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic

Comment: C++ wouldn't have needed `atomic<T*>` if that was the case :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

C++03 does not know about the existance of threads, therefore the concept of atomicity doesn't make much sense for C++03, meaning that it doesn't say anything about that.

C++11 does know about threads, but once again doesn't say anything about the atomicity of assigning pointers. However C++11 does contain `std::atomic<T*>`, which is guaranteed to be atomic.

Note that even if writing to a raw pointer is atomic on your platform the compiler is still free to move that assingment around, so that doesn't really buy you anything.

If you need to write to a pointer which is shared between threads use either `std::atomic<T*>` (or the not yet official `boost::atomic<T*>`, gccs atomic intrinsics or windows Interlocked*) or wrap all accesses to that pointer in mutexes.

Comment: You can get boost.atomic here: http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html

Answer (score 3):

The C++ norm does not define specific threading behavior. Depending on the compiler and the platform, the pointer assignment may or may not be atomic.

Comment: C++11 *does* define a threading behavior and the associated memory model.

Comment: @Frizlab and J.N. you are both correct. As saying Porsche is a sport car is a correct but imprecise, as not every model is a sport car :)