# Is make_pair atomic?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, atomic

```
std::pair<Object, OtherObject*> currentData;

void OnCallback()
{
    Object object = getObject();
    OtherObject* otherObject = new OtherObject();
    currentData = std::make_pair(object, otherObject);
}
```

Is `make_pair` atomic?  Will `make_pair` copy or move the fields from its return value to `currentData`?  If I have another thread accessing the value of `currentData`, is there any potential that `currentData`'s value will be incomplete when it's accessed?

Unfortunately I didn't see any related information in the standard docs for [`make_pair`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/).

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "atomic"? Because it's obviously not atomic in the sense of `std::atomic`.

Comment: `std::make_pair` uses move-semantics, however that does not mean it is atomic in compliance with `std::atomic`

Comment: If not in the sense of `std::atomic` then in what sense do you mean. Because your quoted sense seems to be what `std::atomic` does.

Comment: @LokiAstari I think my entire question boils down to the atomicity of the assignment operator. This helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919818/is-pointer-assignment-atomic-in-c I didn't even bother looking at the `std::atomic` class, but it looks like it's what I want.  Also this helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16320838/when-do-i-really-need-to-use-atomicbool-instead-of-bool

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whether `make_pair()` is or isn't atomic is irrelevant.

> If I have another thread accessing the value of currentData, is there
>   any potential that currentData's value will be incomplete when it's
>   accessed?

The only question here is whether `std::pair`'s assignment operator is atomic, since that's what determines whether the assignment operation is thread-safe or not. What happened before the assignment took place, and how the value that's being assigned came into existence, bears absolutely no relevance on the atomicity of the assignment operation.

This assignment operation is not atomic, and is not thread-safe.

Comment: Separation of creation and assignment is a good point, thanks.