# Is this C++ pointer usage thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-model

Do I need insert fence before "p = tmp" to avoid memory reordering? Is it possible "p=tmp" executed before "(*tmp)[1]=2" due to memory reordering from the view of thread 2 without using fence/atomic/mutex?

thread 1

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p;
auto tmp = new std::map<int, int>;
(*tmp)[1] = 2;
...
(*tmp)[2] = 3;
// do I need insert fence here to make sure above operation on tmp ready before tmp assigned to p?
p = tmp;
```

thread 2

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p; // suppose p initalized with {{1:2}}
assert(p->find(1)->second == 2);
```

Comment: You should always guard your shared resource if one thread writes to it while another might want to access it. Critical section is one instruction here, so no much overhead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is pointer assignment atomic in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8919818/is-pointer-assignment-atomic-in-c)

Comment: this isn't safe, you can make your pointer an atomic or use locks.

Comment: This is undefined behaviour in c++, no amount of fences will save you.

Comment: @MikeVine Why is it undefined?

Comment: @FantasticMrFox there is a data race on p

Comment: @FantasticMrFox fences are completely architecture dependent, without knowing the architecture we can't know if he needs one or two fences. and they are most of the time overkill

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible "p=tmp" executed before "(*tmp)[1]=2" due to memory
>   reordering from the view of thread 2 without using fence/atomic/mutex?

can it happen yes

volatile should be added to the list of things preventing the reordering but volatile would still not protect from the data race

> Do I need insert fence before "p = tmp" to avoid memory reordering?

you need to add a synchronization but fences are often suboptimal and were they are needed is architecture specific. atomic would be better suited in that case

with `#include <atomic>`

thread 1

```
extern std::atomic<const std::map<int, int>*> p;
auto tmp = new std::map<int, int>;
(*tmp)[1] = 2;
...
(*tmp)[2] = 3;
// do I need insert fence here to make sure above operation on tmp ready before tmp assigned to p?
p = tmp;
```

thread 2

```
extern std::atomic<const std::map<int, int>*> p; // suppose p initalized with {{1:2}}
assert(p->find(1)->second == 2);
```

Comment: I prefer to use std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release) before p = tmp for best performance.

Answer (score 1):

You have thread 2 to wait for thread 1 to complete its chunk of work

thread 1

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p;
auto tmp = new std::map<int, int>;
(*tmp)[1] = 2;
...
(*tmp)[2] = 3;
p = tmp;
// set event here
```

thread 2

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p; // suppose p initalized with {{1:2}}
// wait for event here
assert(p->find(1)->second == 2);
```

or you can guard *p* with CS or mutex in both threads but then p should be checked for validity before usage in thread 2

thread 1

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p;
auto tmp = new std::map<int, int>;
// lock mutex here
(*tmp)[1] = 2;
...
(*tmp)[2] = 3;
p = tmp;
// unlock mutex here
```

thread 2

```
extern const std::map<int, int>* p; // suppose p initalized with {{1:2}}
// lock mutex here
// check if p is initialized:
// if (p is ok){
    assert(p->find(1)->second == 2);
// }
// unlock mutex here
```