# Is it always effective to read a variable in the multi-thread environment？

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, kernel, cpu

There is a variable(e.g. int temp;) in the multi-thread environment.
Some threads write to it, with write-lock protected.
while others read the variable, but without any lock.

My question is:
If the variable is writed to be one of element in a SET(e.g. {1, 2, 3}), 
by some threads repeatedly.
Is it always one of that SET, when I read it.

Comment: You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic

Comment: Yes, the answer of Skizz helps me.

Answer (score 4):

The rule is very simple: if two or more threads access the same variable and at least one of those threads writes to it, you **must** synchronize **all** of those accesses. If you do not, the behavior is undefined.

`volatile` won't help here; either use a mutex or a condition variable, or make the variable itself atomic. (And "atomic" means C++11 atomic, not some selection of properties that someone thinks will act pretty well in multi-threaded applications).

Comment: I agree with you. I put the question here because I have seen many code written, supposing the answer of my question is 'YES', which make me very confused. But it may usually 'YES', :)..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will if your variable's type is immutable because SET does not allow duplicates

Refer [SET](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)

Comment: hmm, it seems that you misunderstand my words. My SET here means a set of values, like {1, 2, 3}.

Answer (score 0):

If noone write value from outside of your SET, the value will remains from this SET. You can possibly need to use `volatile` in your case.