# Is it possible to read half-written, corrupt primitive variable when using multithreading in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, memory-corruption

If on one thread I would be writing to a primitive-type variable, such as `int`, and the other would be reading it, would there be a possibility of reading partially modified data, as with more complex data types?

If yes, then would my only rescue be either `atomic` or `mutex` or is there a solution with less performance overhead?

Comment: It's undefined behavior, so anything can happen. For example the reading thead might not even see the changes at all, ever. It doesn't matter that the type involved is a fundamental type or a class type. You need synchronization.

Comment: With regard to the reading thread: any reads after the 1st could be optimised out by the compiler because it can prove that the value never changes after the 1st read.  So, for example,  a loop waiting for a value to be set from the writing thread would never exit as the code to re-read the value was optimised out..

Comment: Same that [Are C++ Reads and Writes of an int Atomic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the wording of the standard yes: accessing the same non-`atomic` object from more than one thread, where at least one access is a write, is undefined behavior. So not only could you see "half-written" or "corrupt" primitive data, *other* things are possible such as corruption of unrelated data, infinite loops, your computer becoming sentient and building a time machine and traveling to the past to convince your ancestors never to pursue the activities that would lead to your birth, segmentation faults, noxious gases being emitted from your USB ports, etc.

*In practice*, I'm not aware of how this could happen on *modern* architectures when writing aligned values of primitive types, other than "wide" primitive types that aren't natively supported by the hardware (e.g., some multi-socket AMD machines fail to write aligned 128-bit values atomically). Compilers will generally emit full-width loads and stores, so I don't know of a realistic scenario where you'd be tripped up by e.g. a compiler transforming a 32-bit store into two 16-bit stores, although it is *perfectly within its rights to*.

That doesn't mean you should do it: the compiler can make *other* assumptions that can trip you up: e.g., that the value never changes and hence it doesn't need to be re-read at all. More importantly, what you may want is `std::atomic` in concert with `std::memory_order_relaxed` in key places which often has zero or almost zero performance implications. It's a sharp tool though.

Comment: "In practice, I'm not aware of how this could happen on modern architectures when writing aligned values of primitive types" - I'm fairly sure some modern ARM chips have some very lax requirements/guarantees in this area and may give surprising results without proper synchronization. And then there's always the huge "it's UB" elephant in the room, so your compiler may screw you over *BIG time*, regardless of the hardware.

Comment: Half written word size variable *probably* won't happen in any case; but the *compiler* will still assume that the variable was not changed. So the act of writing is OK as long as the value isn't changed. ;)

Comment: @JesperJuhl Can you elaborate? What could possibly happen at the asm level? (What happens in a high level compiled language is another story.) How could any hw screw up writing whole words? Also what special asm instr exists to avoid the screw up?

Comment: @JesperJuhl - I am interested in any details if you have them. ARM has a weak memory model, and arguably POWER is even weaker, but none of them split writes, as far as I know. Even going back further, machines which split writes of machine word sized values were basically non-existent. For larger values it can happen, e.g., 64-bit values on 32-bit machines or somewhat famously, 128-bit values on 64-bit AMD machines (but only in very specific scenarios).

Comment: About the UB elephant, I think I covered it well? Fully two of the three paragraphs were about "don't do this, because UB". I'm always going to put in the other part of answer which is "what happens IRL on real compilers" because that's how I roll and without that it wouldn't add anything to the existing answer that was there.

Answer (score 7):

In theory (and also real life), yes. You *must* synchronise access to variables that are read and written by different threads.

Some hardware architectures may not need the synchronization (in which case a competent compiler should just remove it), but *some* architectures have very lax guarantees (like DEC Alpha - and others) and synchronization is very much required.

For portable and predictable results across implentations, you *must* synchronise access to variables. Partial reads/writes *can* happen (usually at 3-o'clock at night at your most important customer when everyone is on vacation).

Not to mention the fact that lacking synchronization, your program contains a data race, and data races are by definition Undefined Behaviour. And once your program contains UB (*anywhere*), your compiler no longer has any restrictions on what code it may generate (for *all* of your program). So even if the hardware guarantees it is safe, the compiler may exploit the presence of theoretical UB to perform optimizations that will break your program - and not necessarily where you expect that breakage to happen.

Comment: Is it somehow (sorry for the lack of a better word) standardized by the standard? In practice (on Windows, Mac and Linux) is it actually needed?

Comment: @YanB. 0) See update to my answer.  1) Depends on the hardware as much as the OS. 2) Also depends on the compiler. Most modern compilers will agressively exploit theoretical UB and may break your program. 3) On a good compiler, unnecessary synchronization will be compiled out anyway, so it doesn't cost you anything and may save your ass.

Comment: How is DEC Alpha special? How can is break atomicity of word size operations?

Comment: I don't know that Alpha broke atomicity, but it was really weird in other respects, e.g., loads or stores that could move forward in time even before instructions they needed to calculate their address, which nothing later did. Also, early versions had no byte writes, so you pretty much wouldn't be able to implement modern C++ efficiently on these since modern C++ (since C++11) essentially requires independent byte writes to implement the non-interference part of the memory model.

Comment: this is overly conservative, and really should be conditioned on the target architecture.   for example in modern x86_64 PC's, t's functionally impossible to have a partial read of a word..   optimizing for hardware is a normal thing